# defaultdict - first argument must be callable or None

Tags: defaultdict

I am trying to do something very simple and just cannot get past the second line.
Python 3.6 version throws an error "First argument must be callable or None" at >>> d = defaultdict(list)

Everywhere, the code is identified as exactly below, but for me the error comes up. This is so simple yet I am stumped. Please advise.

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
d = defaultdict(list)
d.default_factory
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
d.items()
d
```